# StringTokenizer does not seem to work in my program - Java

Tags: java, stringtokenizer

I am making a program about client/server programming in which the user will input a string in the console, and the program will search through every line of a .txt file for that string, and outputs the whole line where that particular string resides.

This is a part of the code where the StringTokenizer is used:

```
String line = "";
boolean wordFound = false;

while((line = bufRead.readLine()) != null) {
    StringTokenizer str = new StringTokenizer(line, ", .();:-?!'");

    while(str.hasMoreTokens()) {
        String next = str.nextToken();
        if(next.equalsIgnoreCase(targetWord)) {
            wordFound = true;
            output = line;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(wordFound) break;
    else output = "Quote not found.";
}
```

The problem is that when I want to search for a string e.g. "you're" or "it's my birthday" (with apostrophe and/or spaces), it gives a false value for boolean wordFound. I tried removing the delimiters " " and "'" but still it doesn't work.

I once modified the code and I sometimes get a true value for boolean wordFound, but now it seems like it does not ignore the case. e.g. I entered "you're", wordFound becomes true. But if I change it to "You're" or "yOu'Re", wordFound is still false.

Can someone help me find a solution to this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your string tokenizer should be:

```
StringTokenizer str = new StringTokenizer(line, ", .();:-?!\"");
```

In your code you have `StringTokenizer(line, ", .();:-?!'");` **i.e. `'` instead of `"`**, which is tokenizing your text `you're"` into `you` and `re"`.